# Why one curl can do https and other can't

Tags: ssl, curl, libcurl

I have run a curl query: `curl https://login:password@mywebsite.com/script/`

I have few curl executables, one installed with cygwin:

1:

```
curl 7.59.0 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin) libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2o zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.18.0 (+libidn2/2.0.2) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.31.0
Release-Date: 2018-03-14
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS Debug IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL Metalink
```

other two that I compiled:

2 - libcurl-vc14-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl :

```
curl 7.60.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.60.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2k WinIDN
Release-Date: 2018-05-16
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL HTTPS-proxy
```

3 - libcurl-vc14-x86-release-static-ssl-static-ipv6-sspi:

```
curl 7.60.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.60.0 WinSSL WinIDN
Release-Date: 2018-05-16
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL
```

1 + 3 can do this 'TSL request', 2 returns error message:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

All the advices I found on this problem is - you have to get the cert file from the server and store it into local store (or tell to curl to ignore the error).

My question is - why is that a proposed answer, when 1 + 3 can do it without that? What is the difference? And what do have 1 + 3 in common that they can do what 2 can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because...

cygwin probably has a CA store locally already as part of its main install. It is used by more tools than just curl.

curl built with the "WinSSL" backend automatically uses the CA store that your windows installation has bundled with the operating system.

Your custom build using OpenSSL needs a CA store to verify the remote server's certificate against...